# Amazon Linux AMI EC2 PHP Function Recognition

Tags: apache-2.2, php, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-ami

I've recently set up the title instance (64bit) on AWS. I have that being said, I've installed httpd and php, both of which are running.

The series of installs executed are as follows:

```
yum install httpd
yum install php
yum install mysql
yum install php-mysql
```

What am I missing with regards to the PHP install? The function library seems to be lacking as both `mb_strlen()` and `imagecreatefromjpeg()` are no longer recognized.

Many thanks for suggested additional installs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

imagecreatefromjpeg is in

```
php-gd
```

mb_strlen is in

```
php-mbstring
```

So install them via

```
yum install php-gd php-mbstring
```

Comment: if you're running php 5.5, you'll need to run ````sudo yum install php55-mbstring````.